# Teams messaging extension cannot reach my service

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I developed a service(using asp.net core) for teams messaging extension, registered a bot. when I sent a message in web chat, my service receives the requests, but after i installed the extension in my teams and click the extension, my service cannot receive any request. I don't know how to wire them up. please help.

Comment: Need more info. What's your manifest? Is your endpoint recieving any traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue when I was developing a teams bot. Microsoft bot framework supports several channels. You need to enable "Teams" channel which is not enabled by default. The reason why web chat works is that the web channel is enabled as default after you create a bot. Hope it helps.